# Sum with dynamic condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, subroutine, sumifs

I have an `Excel` file in which some columns. The Excel is my bank account.

The `D` column is `date`, and not just for one day,its the days of a week.
I want to some all columns in that has the same date, and insert it in new `cell`.ex : for a week i should have 7 sum.

Here is some possible data from the sheet.

```
  date(Column D)     Money(Column K)        Sum of same date(Column N)
    1396/1/1                2300              
    1396/1/1                1000                      3300 // some of the same date
    1396/1/2                1200
    1396/1/2                 320                      1550 // some of the same date
```

It is possible with Excel functions? Does I need a `subroutin`?

Comment: Sumifs() should do what you want.

Comment: I had visited some pages that uses sumif.
but all of them have static condition.
I want it dynamically
Could you give a sample if it can do dynamically?
I mean I do not want to enter the date every time.
I want as i opened Excel file i see the sums in some cells.

Comment: You will need to provide data and expected outcomes.  Your details are lacking.

Comment: You mean I add some pictures?

Comment: I would prefer data as text in the original post so we can copy and paste.

Comment: Ok, I do it now.

Comment: (***Make sure to obfuscate your data***, since you mention it's Bank data. Generate fake numbers/text so we don't actually see real data.)

Comment: @ScottCraner - SO will only let me upvode '*I would prefer data as text in the original post so we can copy and paste.*' once!

Comment: Are your dates always sorted?

Comment: Yes sir, It can not be blank.

Answer (score 1):

In L2 try,

```
=IF(ROW()=MATCH(D2, D:D), SUMIFS(K:K, D:D, D2), TEXT(,))
```

Fill down.

[image]

Comment: It took me a second to figure out the match part.  I was thinking that it would find the first and that I had caught you in an error.  But I should have figured that it was me in the wrong.  I missed that the third criterion was missing.  I like that method and I am going to steal it.

Comment: Only for data sorted in an ascending manner. I don't usually trust small samples like the one the OP supplied but it is bank data and that should typically be in an ascending order.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but it gives me Error I tested it in liberoffice ( Ubuntu ! ) even ! I have windows xp and excel 2007. I entered your formula in N1, copy and paste your formula in N1. But it says : The formula you typed contains an error

Comment: Try a semi-colon instead of a comma. A comma is generally used but some regional list separators are semi-colons. Tnis is oe of the reasons why asking for original effort is important; it instantly solves situations like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(D2<>D3,SUMIF(D:D,D2,K:K),"")
```

Then copy down

[image]

Comment: It returns zero sir.
I just copy 4 column of each data.
It is more than 4 column.
I copy the formula in one cell and then it returns zero.

Comment: Your data needs to be representative of the actual data.  As you can see per your example the formula works.  You need to give a full example and not a part.

Comment: These are real data.
But not the whole sheet, in the other column of sheet these are description and the name of the account and others.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but it gives me Error 
I tested it in liberoffice ( Ubuntu ! ) even !
I have windows xp and excel 2007.
I entered your formula in N1, copy and paste your formula in N1.
But it says : 

`The formula you typed contains an error`.

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` as your deliminator between criteria?  Try changing out the `,` for `;`

Comment: Now display nothing 
Is it so hard or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you then drag the formula down?  It will show blank in some and numbers in others.

Comment: Sir, it works now.
But just for one date.
For example i have a sheet that has 40 rows with 6 seven different dates.
I copy the formula in N1( edited formula as 
`=IF(D2<>D40,SUMIF(D:D,D2,K:K),"")`  ( I changed D3 to D40, cause in that case that returns nothing) it gives me the first date sum value and not the other days.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to work with Sumif or SUMIFS and your Formula should like,

SUMIFS(D2:D10, C2:C10,">="&TODAY()-7, C2:C10,"<="&TODAY())

Or it should be like,

=SUMIFS(D2:D10, C2:C10,">="&A2, C2:C10,"<="&A3)

Or

=SUMIF(D2:D10, C2:C10,">="&TODAY())

NB: Sum Range is D2:D10 & C2:C10 is Criteria range. 
In 2nd example A2 & A3 Cells holds Date value.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir, 
I have updated my question.
Could you take a look at this?
I want it dynamically and not just for a week.

Comment: Hey my this example is how to use a Dynamic data range 

=SUMIFS(D2:D10, C2:C10,">="&A2, C2:C10,"<="&A3)

Here A2 & A3 are dynamic cells where you can write any Date values,, but it must be any 2 from Criteria Range C2:C10.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but it gives me Error I tested it in liberoffice ( Ubuntu ! ) even ! I have windows xp and excel 2007. I entered your formula in N1, copy and paste your formula in N1. But it says : The formula you typed contains an error

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Dates are in Col A & you want to Sum values in Column B, so instead of Sumif you can use this,

C2=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A$2:A$10)=ROW()-1),--(B$2:B$10))

NB: MONTH function will pull the Month value from A2 and add with corresponding Cell value in B, drag the formula below.

Comment: Did you saw my raw data?
The date is SHAMSI.

Comment: Yeah I have seen your Dates are in Column D and Value to Sum in K,, so you change Cell address accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but it gives me Error I tested it in liberoffice ( Ubuntu ! ) even ! I have windows xp and excel 2007. I entered your formula in N1, copy and paste your formula in N1. But it says : The formula you typed contains an error

Comment: Possibly in Column C and in A2, A3 Dates are in different formats, if in col C date format is, 
Year/Month/Date, then in both A2 & A3 also in same format. 
Please check.